# How to create an area or surface from point objects in Smallworld with MAGIK?

Tags: smallworld-gis, magik

In Smallworld i have a geometry-set with simple-Point objects.

Is there a way to create a polygon, a surface or an area from these simple-Points with Magik? I prefer a pseudo-area, but these is not essential.

Later i would like to Intersect these area with other Point-Objects.

Answer (score 2):

there are many ways to create an area from points. What is your goal? Do you want the Enclosing Circle or the Voronoi Polygons or the Convex Hulls of the points?
If you look in the User Manual of the Professional Application you will find a chapter about Analysis for Proximity and Clustering. These are all about converting points to areas.

The module point_set_analysis_plugin contains all the software that does these analysis, so you can simply lookup the function you want to perform and copy the source code from there.

If you find the source code confusing, please let me know what kind of area you require and I can provide you a code-snippet that does the work...
mailto:frank.van.ham@realworld-systems.com